# Neutron Quantum Gateway vs Neutron API, which charm to use?

Tags: networking, juju, openstack

We are running 14.04 Trusty/Juno and when deploying "Neutron" we have a question of which charm we should use or if both are to be used.  Quantum Gateway or Neutron API or both.  The charm descriptions appear identical.